# Apache error for setting django on webfaction

Tags: django, apache

im setting up a django project on webfaction, and after all configuration the website is showing a 200 error. In the apache error log this is the info:

```
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=803732): Target WSGI script '/home/hammad/webapps/gccfishing/gccFishing/gccFishing/gccFishing/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=803732): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/hammad/webapps/gccfishing/gccFishing/gccFishing/gccFishing/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/hammad/webapps/gccfishing/gccFishing/gccFishing/gccFishing/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/hammad/webapps/gccfishing/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/hammad/webapps/gccfishing/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import logging
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/hammad/webapps/gccfishing/lib/python2.7/warnings.py", line 107
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     except _OptionError, msg:
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]                        ^
[Fri Nov 01 15:04:38 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The error was caused because of mismatch between python versions. The mod_wsgi application on webfaction was running on python 3 and my app was using python 2.7.

Re-created a new mod_wsgi application with python2.7 and everything is now working.

Comment: Please accept this answer so that readers know this question is already answered without having to read the answers themselves.